# Encoding Conversion filed when text file is created in UNIX environment (with UTF-8 without BOM encoded)

Tags: c#, file, encoding, character-encoding, filestream

I have a method which will convert any file encoding to Windows(1252).

But it is not converting when the file is created in UNIX environment (with UTF-8 without BOM Encoding) and obviously file does not have any BOM. It happens only when this scenario occures.

This is my code.

```
public static void ConvertFileEncoding(string srcFile, Encoding srcEncoding, string tempFile)
    {

          using (var reader = new StreamReader(srcFile,srcEncoding,false))
          using (var writer = new StreamWriter(System.IO.File.Open(tempFile, FileMode.Create), Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
            {
                char[] buf = new char[1024];

                while (true)
                {
                    int count = reader.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    writer.Write(buf, 0, count);
                }
            }

            System.IO.File.Copy(tempFile, srcFile, true); // Source file is replaced with Temp file 
            DeleteTempFile(tempFile);

            // TO DO  -- Log Sucess Details
    }
```

**Can anyone suggest better way of doing this.**

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case you can simply change...

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(srcFile,srcEncoding,false))
{
    ...
}
```

TO...

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(srcFile))
{
    ...
}
```

It's not required to define the encoding on StreamReader, it works very well without.

Another point is that there are unhandled exceptions in your code; and useless overwrites in some cases.

I created a similar function some time ago. I modified it a bit to share it here as example:

```
namespace Example
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;

    public static class TextEx
    {
        public static void ChangeEncoding(string srcFile, Encoding encoding)
        {
            if (srcFile == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(srcFile));
            if (encoding == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(encoding));
            if (!File.Exists(srcFile))
                throw new FileNotFoundException();

            // get the current encoding of the source file and cancel if it equals
            // with the specified encoding
            if (encoding.Equals(GetEncoding(srcFile)))
                return;

            // creates the destination file on the same location to be sure we
            // have rights to write there
            var newFile = string.Concat(srcFile, ".new");
            File.Create(newFile).Close();

            // read the source file and write to the destination file
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(srcFile))
            {
                var ca = new char[4096];
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(newFile, true, encoding))
                {
                    int i;
                    while ((i = sr.Read(ca, 0, ca.Length)) > 0)
                        sw.Write(ca, 0, i);
                }
            }

            // generate the hashcode of the source file for comparison
            var srcHash = GetFileHash(srcFile);
            // generate the hashcode of the finished destination file and compare
            // it with the hashcode of the source file
            var newHash = GetFileHash(newFile);
            if (srcHash.Equals(newHash))
            {
                // delete the destination file if there are no changes inside
                File.Delete(newFile);
                return;
            }

            // overwrite the file if it is different
            File.Delete(srcFile);
            File.Move(newFile, srcFile);
        }

        public static Encoding GetEncoding(string file)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(file));
            if (!File.Exists(file))
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            Encoding encoding;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(file, true))
            {
                sr.Peek();
                encoding = sr.CurrentEncoding;
            }
            return encoding;
        }

        public static string GetFileHash(string file)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(file));
            if (!File.Exists(file))
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            string hash;
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
                using (var fs = File.OpenRead(file))
                {
                    var bytes = md5.ComputeHash(fs);
                    hash = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
                }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that there is an unhandled exception if the source file is locked by another process. But I think the solution that I have created is too overkill to share it here.

USAGE:

```
Example.TextEx.ChangeEncoding("C:\\example.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

Comment: Why I made it buffer wise write because in case huge files, the memory out of exception may occur..

Comment: This part of your code was better as well. I updated my code. I didn't change it before, because you were looking for different ways to find out what is the best for you. Btw... what's with your problem?! I have tested it, and for me it works very well.